# Why php-fpm status max active processes can be larger than pm.max_children?

Tags: php

I set the pm.max_children = 100 and pm = dynamic in my phpfpm.conf and enable phpfpm status api in nginx.conf. But I found the "max active processes = 108" in the result from status api. Why active processes can be larger than pm.max_children ?

```
pool:                 www
process manager:      dynamic
start time:           14/Feb/2019:11:22:50 +0800
start since:          7077
accepted conn:        513727
listen queue:         0
max listen queue:     21
listen queue len:     128
idle processes:       1
active processes:     19
total processes:      20
max active processes: 108
max children reached: 0
slow requests:        0
```

This is my config in phpfpm.conf:

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 100
pm.start_servers = 12
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 20
pm.max_requests = 100
```